# How do you get the indexPath.section and indexPath.row when a button in a cell is tapped?

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview divide in section, I must to print the number of row and section when I tap the button in a cell. How can I get this?

Comment: @vadian, As form the question what I understand is that it is not about detecting button in cell it is about getting row and section from that cell

You can use that closure in the link vadian provided in addition you can pass the indexpath as the parameter of the closure

Comment: The linked question describes a way *to get the indexPath.section and indexPath.row when a button in a cell is tapped*.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. When it gets called, an NSIndexPath will be passed in that has the section and row properties on it.

This method will be called every time a tableview cell is pressed. The index path will be the index path of the cell that was pressed.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview

EDIT:

I misread the question. When the button is pressed, get the TableViewCell from the button by accessing the superview of the button. Then use the TableView's indexPathForCell method to get the indexPath of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `indexPath` inside your cell and retreive it when the button is pressed.

**Table view controller**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! CustomTableCell
    cell.indexPath = indexPath

    return cell
}
```

**Custom table cell**

```
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var indexPath: IndexPath!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a need to store the index path into a custom tableview cell when the index path is passed into the tableView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath delegate method.

Comment: Keep in mind that OP wants to retreive the `indexPath` when a **button** is pressed, not the cell itself.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. It's still unnecessary to create a custom cell. When the button is pressed, grab the tableview cell with the super view property of the button. Then used the tableview's indexPathForCell method to get the index path.